# Get value from client side script and override server side script

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Below are my server side and client side JavaScript files. I have hard coded queryObject in server side script I can display the body in client-side.
The problem is how to get value from client side for queryObject variable in server side and override the existing values.
In short, current program converts USD to GBP as I hard-coded it. I want a way to access queryObject from client side and give my own values.

```
//=====================Server Side Script========================//

var request = require('request');
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
// const hbs = require("hbs");

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const pathPublic = path.join(__dirname, "../public");
const pathView = path.join(__dirname, "../templates/views");
app.set("view engine", "hbs");
app.set("views", pathView);
app.use(express.static(pathPublic));

app.get("", (req, res) => {
  res.render("home", {
    title: "Currency Converter"
  });  
});


app.get("/currency", (req, res) => {
    const uri = "https://currency-exchange.p.rapidapi.com/exchange?",
    headers={
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'currency-exchange.p.rapidapi.com',
    'x-rapidapi-key': 'b13c4f3d67msh8143a7f1298de7bp1e8586jsn4453f885a4e7'
    }
    const queryObject  = {
        q: 1,
        from: 'USD',
        to: 'GBP'
        };

    request({
        url:uri,
        qs:queryObject,
        headers: headers
    },
function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred

    } else if(response && body) {
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
        res.json({'body': body}); // Print JSON response.
    }
    })
});

app.listen(port, () => {
console.log("Server is running on port " + port);
});

//=====================Client Side Script========================//

const currency = document.querySelector("#currency");
const text1= document.querySelector(".text1");
const text2= document.querySelector(".text2");
const text3= document.querySelector(".text3");
const Form = document.querySelector("form");

function refreshPage() {
  window.location.reload();

}

Form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();


fetch("http://localhost:3000/currency").then(response => {
  response.json().then(data => {
    if (data.error) {
      console.log(data.error);
    } else {
      currency.textContent = data.body;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION:**

In order to modify any values in server, you have to send appropriate HTTP method (eg: POST) with appropriate data in it. And let the server handle the request to change the content of object to make an API call from there.

I made some changes in your code for demonstration and install **'cors', 'body-parser' module** and other missing modules to make it run.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>  
    <div id="currencyType">
        <select id="fromCurrency">
          <option value="USD">USD</option>
          <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
        </select>
        <select id="toCurrency">
          <option value="USD">USD</option>
          <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="getCurrency">Get Currency</button>
    <div id="currency" name="currency" type="text"></div>

<script>
    const currency = document.querySelector("#currency");
    const btn = document.getElementById("getCurrency");
    function refreshPage() {
        window.location.reload();
    }
    btn.addEventListener("click", e => {
        var fromCurrency = document.getElementById("fromCurrency");
        fromCurrency = fromCurrency.options[fromCurrency.selectedIndex].value;
        var toCurrency = document.getElementById("toCurrency");
        toCurrency = toCurrency.options[toCurrency.selectedIndex].value;
        var data = {
            fromCurrency: fromCurrency,
            toCurrency: toCurrency
        };
        // calls the API with POST method with data in it
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/currency", {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }).then(response => {
            response.json().then(data => {
                if (data.error) {
                  console.log(data.error);
                } else {
                  currency.textContent = "1 " + fromCurrency + " = " + data.body + " " + toCurrency;
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**NodeJS:**

```
var request = require('request');
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
var cors = require('cors')
// const hbs = require("hbs");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const pathPublic = path.join(__dirname, "public");
const pathView = path.join(__dirname, "templates/views");
app.set("view engine", "hbs");
app.set("views", pathView);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.static(pathPublic));
app.use(cors())


app.get("", (req, res) => {
  res.render("home", {
    title: "Currency Converter"
  });  
});    
app.post("/currency", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const uri = "https://currency-exchange.p.rapidapi.com/exchange?",
    headers={
        'x-rapidapi-host': 'currency-exchange.p.rapidapi.com',
        'x-rapidapi-key': 'b13c4f3d67msh8143a7f1298de7bp1e8586jsn4453f885a4e7'
    }
    const queryObject  = {
        q: 1,
        from: req.body.fromCurrency,
        to: req.body.toCurrency
    };
    console.log(queryObject);
    request({
        url:uri,
        qs:queryObject,
        headers: headers
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred

        } else if(response && body) {
            console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
            res.json({'body': body}); // Print JSON response.
        }
        })
    });
app.listen(port, () => {
console.log("Server is running on port " + port);
});
```

**Sample output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll code in client-side to send a request to server-side containing the query object. 
And on the server-side, you pick up your query object.

There are so many ways of doing this.

1. Using a GET request with parameters - On the server-side your query object will be available at `res.query.params`
2. Using a POST request - On the server side you will want to use the [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) plugin for parsing your response body and hence, your data will be available at `res.body`

[Read on body parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)